# Converting an object into a String by using JacksonFactory

Tags: android, jackson2

I'm using `JacksonFactory` and want to convert `object` into `String`.

Here is my code that I'm using but it's not working.

**InformerItem**

```
 public class InformerItem {

    private String filePath;
    private String fileName;

    // getter setter
}
```

**StorageInformer**

```
public class StorageInformer {

    private List<InformerItem> informerItems;

    // getter setter constructor etc
}
```

**ConvertObjectIntoString**

```
 InformerItem infoItem = new InformerItem("name of file", "path of file");
 InformerItem infoItem2 = new InformerItem("second name", "second path");

 List<InformerItem> informerList = new ArrayList();
 informerList.add(infoItem);
 informerList.add(infoItem2);

 StorageInformer storageInformer = new StorageInformer();
 storageInformer.setInformerList(informerList);

JacksonFactory jacksonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
String storageInformerString = jacksonFactory.toString(storageInformer.getInformerItems().get(0));
        String objectInString = jacksonFactory.toString(storageInformer);
        String anotherString = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance().toString(storageInformer);
        String prettyString = jacksonFactory.toPrettyString(storageInformer);

 // all these methods are returning {} or [{}] some kind of this.
```

There is no error but it's not properly converting object into string.

**Note: I don't want to use `ObjectMapper`**

Please let me know what's the problem here

Comment: Why don't you use Google's gson? It's simpler

Comment: I don't want to add another library.